# How to update menu item in my case?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Basically, when you click on register menu item, an alert dialog pops up and after you click register, request is sent and the activity is recreated (is this the best way, can I refresh activity after alert dialog is closed without recreating it?). I have a boolean that I put in shared preferences, and according to that, the menu item should update, but it stays the same. I have to exit the activity and next time I return to it, then it is updated. But, when I logout, the menu is automatically updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPreferenceAdapter = new PreferenceAdapter(this);
    loginNo = mPreferenceAdapter.getLoginNo();
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isLoggedIn = mPrefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);

    i = getIntent();
    bundle = i.getBundleExtra("products");
    parcelableProducts = bundle.getParcelable("parcelProducts");
    parcelableShop = bundle.getParcelable("parcelShop");
    bundle.putParcelable("parcelProductsFragment", parcelableProducts);
    bundle.putParcelable("parcelProductsFragmentShop", parcelableShop);

    shop = Parcels.unwrap(parcelableShop);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setUpViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    menuItemRegister = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_register);

    if (loginNo == 0) {
        menuItemRegister.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        changeLoginItem(isLoggedIn);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_peems:
            i = new Intent(this, PeemActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_shops:
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_cart:
            i = new Intent(this, CheckoutActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_login:
            //loginDialog();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_register:
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                logout();
            } else {
                registerDialog();
            }

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void changeLoginItem(boolean isLoggedIn) {
    String logOut = getResources().getString(R.string.btnLogout);
    String logIn = getResources().getString(R.string.btnRegister);
    this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    menuItemRegister.setTitle(isLoggedIn ? logOut : logIn);
}

private void registerDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_dialog, null);
    Button btnRegister = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    etFirstName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
    etLastName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
    etEmail = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerInShop();
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}

private void logout() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            mEditor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
            mEditor.apply();
            mPreferenceAdapter.removeLoginNo();
            changeLoginItem(false);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

private void registerInShop() {
    JSONObject shopInfoJSON = new JSONObject();
    try {
        shopInfoJSON.put("ShopNumber", String.valueOf(shop.getShopNo()));
        shopInfoJSON.put("Server", String.valueOf(shop.getServer()));
        shopInfoJSON.put("Db", String.valueOf(shop.getDb()));
        shopInfoJSON.put("DbUser", String.valueOf(shop.getDbUser()));
        shopInfoJSON.put("DbPass", String.valueOf(shop.getDbPass()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject userInfoJSON = new JSONObject();
    try {
        userInfoJSON.put("FirstName", etFirstName.getText().toString());
        userInfoJSON.put("LastName", etLastName.getText().toString());
        userInfoJSON.put("Email", etEmail.getText().toString());
        userInfoJSON.put("Password", etPassword.getText().toString());
        userInfoJSON.put("Honorific", "Monsieur");
        userInfoJSON.put("Company", "Company 1");
        userInfoJSON.put("Company2", "company 2");
        userInfoJSON.put("Address", "address");
        userInfoJSON.put("Address2", "address2");
        userInfoJSON.put("PostalCode", "1000");
        userInfoJSON.put("City", "SomeCity");
        userInfoJSON.put("Country", "SomeCountry");
        userInfoJSON.put("Tel", "123123");
        userInfoJSON.put("Mobile", "569852");
        userInfoJSON.put("DOB", "1985-05-20");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    JSONObject rootJSON = new JSONObject();
    try {
        rootJSON.put("ShopInfo", shopInfoJSON);
        rootJSON.put("UserInfo", userInfoJSON);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest registerInShopRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API.REGISTER_IN_SHOP, rootJSON, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response Register: " + response);
            int loginNo = 0;
            try {
                loginNo = response.getInt("LoginNo");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mPreferenceAdapter.saveLoginNo(loginNo);
            mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            mEditor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
            mEditor.apply();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response Error Register: " + error);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put(KEY_X_PROVIDER, "some");
            headers.put(KEY_AUTHORIZATION, "");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(registerInShopRequest);
}

private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(WishlistFragment.newInstance(), "Wishlist");
    adapter.addFragment(HistoryFragment.newInstance(), "History");
    adapter.addFragment(OffersFragment.newInstance(bundle), "Offers");
    adapter.addFragment(ProductsFragment.newInstance(bundle), "Products");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the parent class for your activity just Activity or AppcompatActivity?

Comment: @hars AppCompatActivity

Comment: hence use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); instead of invalidateOptionsMenu(); and you shouldn't need to recreate your activity.

Comment: @hars Where should I put `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` exactly?

Comment: @hars Does not work.